# How do I set a network proxy with Network Manager?

Tags: network-manager, internet, broadband

I am a student and using Ubuntu 10.04 and Windows 7 as dual boot.

In my college, we have a proxy server, so all I need to use the internet is set the proxy settings in `Preferences -> Network Proxy` and I am set to go.

At my home, I have a broadband connection that requires me to enter my username and password and then its all set on Windows. However, I have no idea how to get it right with Ubuntu.

Once I tried doing that by setting the PPPOE settings and then it worked on Ubuntu too, but when I came back to college, the internet stopped working.

All I remember is that I did some stuff with setting some `Network Manager` stuff to `false` or something like that, and it continued working with the proxy server too.

Please help me with this, so that I can easily use internet both at home and college too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the interface you want to use to connect to the internet isn't configured in **/etc/network/interfaces**, since that will interfere with NetworkManager handling it.

You should probably also check whether the PPPoE connection you're using, if it's configured in NetworkManager, isn't set to *Connect Automatically*, since if it is... then it will connect automatically rather than connecting to a non-PPPoE connection profile.

If your PPPoE connection is configured in NetworkManager, you will find it by right-clicking on the NetworkManager icon in gnome-panel, and clicking "Manage Connections...", then going to the **DSL** tab.

If it doesn't show up there, make sure you don't have special settings for *eth0* under **/etc/network/interfaces**; any line starting with *iface eth0* should be removed from there for NetworkManager to take control of that device.

Comment: Thanks. How can I check whether the PPPoE connection I am using is configured in NetworkManager? I remember last time, I had to go through the console to set the PPPoE settings. Can you elaborate your answer, also describing what NetworkManager does and why is this problem arising?